# How to use the LEFT function to copy and paste a subset of a range of cells into another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a script that finds individual receipts from a combined.csv document that is generated after a series of scripts performs other processing on the data. I would like to take the ID number of the receipt and split it out across different sheets in the same workbook. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub CleanData()
Range("A:A").Sort Key1:=Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
Range("W1").Value = "Receipt Number"
Range("W2").Value = Left(Range("A2"), 4)
End Sub
```

This effectively copy over one line of data, but I am struggling to find a way to get it to grab the entire contents of the column, take the first 4 characters of the cell and then copy the entire contents of that into another column.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you will need to loop through each row to extract the characters you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Formula, automatic Fill-Down, and then converting to values:

```
'Column W to same length as Column A
With Range(Range("W2"), Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,22))
    .Formula = "=Left(A2, 4)" 'Apply Formula, with auto-fill-down
    .Calculate 'Calculate results of Formulae
    .Value = .Value 'Convert Formulae to Values
End With
```